# Creating an identity matrix of size 16x16 using 2 for loops with ranges (1,5)

Tags: python

I am trying to create a 16x16 identity matrix in python by using nested for loops.

```
import numpy as np
total = []
for i in range(1,5):
    for j in range(1,5):
        row = 16*[0]
        total.append(row)
mat = np.matrix(total)
```

How do I modify this to get an identity matrix? The ranges cannot be changed.

Comment: Seems like a lot of constraints to do something quite simple, so presumably this is an assignment? Also, it doesn't look like you're using numpy anywhere here

Comment: numpy is used only too convert list of lists to matrix.

Comment: Can you let us know where are you struggling? What problems are you having?

Comment: Why don't you use numpy.identity()

Comment: How do I use i and j to index the list 'row' and set the necessary value to 1?

Comment: I can't use anything except this

Comment: Have you tried defining the 2d array beforehand, and assigning to it?

Comment: Cannot do that either, I have to do it like this, which is why it is so hard

Comment: Not so hard... Right now you're nowhere near, you're not assigning a 1 anywhere. So perhaps define a counter, and increase it in each loop? Then just change the a value  in `row` at the corresponding index

Comment: I know I am not assigning 1 right now because everything I tried was wrong. I know using a counter will do it, but is there a way to index using i and j?

Comment: The index of the item in the row that should be set to 1 is `4*(i-1) + (j-1)`.

Comment: Don't use `numpy.matrix` for anything. Always use `np.array`

Comment: Thank you so much! It works!

Comment: The constraints do not allow that.

Comment: Fixed it, my bad on that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can follow this. It is done here simply. Note that there are many ways to do this. You can also follow the second way I uploaded below.

```
import numpy as np
total =[]
for i in range(1,17):
    row=[]
    for j in range(1,17):
        if i==j:
            row.append(1)
        else:
            row.append(0)
    total.append(row)
mat = np.array(total)
```

Alternative way:

```
matrix = np.asmatrix(np.eye(16), dtype=int)
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually it is much easier to create your *matrix* as:

```
mat = np.asmatrix(np.eye(16), dtype=int)
```

But if you insist on usage of 2 nested loops, with ranges *(1, 5)*,
you can do it as follows:

```
total = []
row = [1] + [0] * 15
for _ in range(1,5):
    for _ in range(1,5):
        total.append(row)
        row = np.roll(row, 1).tolist()
mat = np.matrix(total)
```

Note that each loop is executed actually **4** times, so the total number
of executions is just **16**.

Even *i* and *j*, which you used in your code, are not needed
(they are never used), so I put *_* instead of them.

Comment: I think another user got it but I'll look into this too. Thanks!